# "Go to function" command in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code has a "Go to symbol" command, which can go to either a variable name or a function. However what I usually want is to jump to a function name, so I'm wondering is there any command or shortcut to do this?

Answer (score 22):

For jumping to function in currently opened file use `Ctrl+Shift+O`.

From docs:

> You can navigate symbols inside a file with Ctrl+Shift+O. By typing : the symbols will be grouped by category. Press Up or Down and navigate to the place you want.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_go-to-symbol

Answer (score 8):

In VSCode `Ctrl+T` shortcut put the focus on the dialog where you can type the name of the symbol you want to navigate to.

From [VSDocs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings):

```
Key                          Command              Command id
⌘T (Windows, Linux Ctrl+T)  Show All Symbols     workbench.action.showAllSymbols
```

It relays on the support installed maybe via plugins. In order to navigate to symbols on a language, [the support for that language must be installed](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2637). It works fine for me on Angular projects with Typescript symbols.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `:` to classify symbols by type

Eg:    `@:your-function`

Refered from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60278165/vs-code-go-to-symbol-nowv1-42-showing-variables-object-and-properties-how-to
Added as answer as I can't comment

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and  a [help]. Please note the reference link quoted by @mimo is better than yours.

Comment: This answer was actually what I needed, but also I feel it answers the primary question properly, great find!